# formulario para editar un input file en php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Buenas tardes hice un formulario para agregar documentos en pdf para que se guarde en una carpeta y la ruta en la base de datos, hasta ahí todo bien, porque incluso lo puedo visualizar en un listado aparte.

```
<?php
include "dbcon.php";
$nombre_asignatura = $_POST['nombre_asignatura'];
$rutaPrograma = "";
        if ($_FILES["plan_estudio"]["type"] == "application/pdf") {
            $nombre = mt_rand(10, 999);
            $rutaPrograma = "plan_clases/Prog-" . $nombre . ".pdf";
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["plan_estudio"]["tmp_name"], $rutaPrograma);
$query_insert = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO asignatura(nombre_asignatura,plan_estudio)VALUES('$nombre_asignatura','$rutaPrograma')");
            if ($query_insert) {
                $alert = '<p class="msg_save">Asignatura creada correctamente.</p>';
            } else {
                $alert = '<p class="msg_error">Error al crear la asignatura.</p>';
            }}}}?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head><body>
            <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">               
            <label for="Descripcion">Nombre de la asignatura:</label>
                <input type="text" name="nombre_asignatura">
             <label>Plan curricular anual:</label>
                <input type="file" name="plan_estudio" accept="application/pdf">
                <input type="submit" value="&#128190; Guardar" class="btn_save">
            </form></body></html>
```

El problema es que necesito obligatoriamente crear un formulario para editar tanto el nombre de la asignatura como el archivo que se a subido. O sea:

- Si agrego una nueva asignatura y no subo el pdf del plan curricular, ir al editor para subirlo
- Si agrego una asignatura con su pdf de plan curricular y después solo editar el nombre de la asignatura pero que no se me borre la ruta con el pdf
- Si quiero editar para cambiar unicamente el pdf

No sé si me hago entender; he buscado tutoriales acerca de eso y no he podido encontrar ninguno.

Este es el formulario para editar, si pudieran ayudarme con eso, no sé que está mal

```
<?php   
    include "dbcon.php";
        $id_asignatura         = $_POST['id_asignatura'];
        $nombre_asignatura     = $_POST['nombre_asignatura'];
        $sql_update = mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE asignatura SET nombre_asignatura = '$nombre_asignatura' WHERE id_asignatura= $id_asignatura ");
                if($sql_update){
                    $alert='<p class="msg_save">Asignatura actualizada correctamente.</p>';
                }else{
                    $alert='<p class="msg_error">Error al actualizar la asignatura.</p>';
                }
    //Mostrar Datos
    if(empty($_REQUEST['id']))
    {
        header('Location: lista_asignatura.php');
    }
    $id_asignatura = $_REQUEST['id'];
    $sql= mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT id_asignatura, nombre_asignatura,plan_estudio,plan_estudio
  from asignatura WHERE id_asignatura= $id_asignatura ");
    $result_sql = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
    if($result_sql == 0){
        header('Location: lista_asignatura.php');
    }else{
        $option = '';
        while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $id_asignatura         = $data['id_asignatura'];
        $nombre_asignatura     = $data['nombre_asignatura'];
        $plan_estudio          = $data['plan_estudio'];
        }   } ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></head><body>
            <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="hidden" name="id_asignatura" value="<?php echo $id_asignatura; ?>">
                <label for="Descripcion"> Nombre de la asignatura:</label>
                <input type="text" name="nombre_asignatura" id="Descripcion" value="<?php echo $nombre_asignatura; ?>">
                <input type="submit" value="&#128190; Actualizar" class="btn_save">
</form></body></html>
```

Este es el código del listado

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['id_tu'] != 1 and $_SESSION['id_tu'] != 2) {
    header("location: ./");
}

include "dbcon.php";
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $id_asignatura = $_REQUEST['id'];
    $DeleteRegistro = ("DELETE FROM asignatura WHERE id_asignatura= '" . $id_asignatura . "' ");
    mysqli_query($connection, $DeleteRegistro);
}

$addConditional = '';
if (array_key_exists('id', $_REQUEST)) {
    $id_curso = $_REQUEST['id'];
    $query = "SELECT * from curso WHERE id_curso= $id_curso";
    $result = $connection->query($query);
    $curso = $result->fetch_array();
    $titulo = $curso['descrip_curso'];
    $addConditional = "WHERE fk_id_curso_asignatura = $id_curso";
}
$por_pagina = 10;

$pagina = empty($_GET['pagina']) ? 1 : $_GET['pagina'];
$desde = ($pagina - 1) * $por_pagina;

$query = "SELECT count(*) as total_registros from asignatura $addConditional";
$results = $connection->query($query);
$result = $results->fetch_array();
$total_registro = $result['total_registros'];
$total_paginas = ceil($total_registro / $por_pagina);

$query = "SELECT a.id_asignatura, a.nombre_asignatura, a.plan_estudio, a.estado_asignatura, a.fk_id_curso_asignatura, c.id_curso, c.descrip_curso from asignatura a INNER JOIN curso c ON a.fk_id_curso_asignatura = c.id_curso $addConditional ORDER BY id_curso ASC LIMIT $desde,$por_pagina";

$results = $connection->query($query);

$table = '';
while ($result = $results->fetch_object()) {
    $plan_estudio = '';
    $estado = $result->estado_asignatura == 1 ? '<span class="activo">Activo</span>' : '<span class="desactivo">Desactivo</span>';
    if ($result->plan_estudio != "") {
        $plan_estudio = '<a href="' . $result->plan_estudio . '" target="_black"">Ver plan curricular anual</a>';
    } else {
        $plan_estudio = 'No tiene plan curricular anual';
    }

    $table .= "<tr>
                <td>$result->nombre_asignatura</td>
                <td>$plan_estudio</td>
                <td>$result->descrip_curso</td>
                <td>$estado</td>
                <td class='linkers'>
                        <a class='link_edit' href='editar_asignatura.php?id=$result->id_asignatura'><i class='fas fa-pencil-square'></i> </a>
                        
                </td>
            </tr>";
}

$paginador = '';
if ($pagina != 1) {
    $paginador .= "<li><a href='?pagina=1'><i class='fa fa-fast-backward'></i></a></li><li><a href='?pagina=" . ($pagina - 1) . "'><i class='fa fa-backward'></i></a></li>";
}

for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_paginas; $i++) {
    if ($i == $pagina) {
        $paginador .= '<li class="pageSelected">' . $i . '</li>';
    } else {
        $paginador .= '<li><a href="?pagina=' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a></li>';
    }
}

if ($pagina != $total_paginas) {
    $paginador .= '<li><a href="?pagina=' . ($pagina + 1) . '"><i class="fa fa-forward"></i></a></li><li><a href="?pagina=' . $total_paginas . ' "><i class="fa fa-fast-forward"></i></a></li>';
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="imagenes/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/buscador.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <title>Escuela Narcisa de Jesus</title>
</head>
<?php include('form/header.php'); ?>

<body>
    <?php include('form/titulo_imagen.php'); ?>
    <section id="container">
        <h1 class="Titulo_lista"><i class='fas fa-list'> Lista de asignaturas</i></h1>
        <a href="agregar_asignatura.php" class="btn_new"><i class='fas fa-plus-circle'></i> Agregar asignatura</a>
        <form action="" method="get" class="form_search">
            <input id="FiltrarContenido" type="text" aria-label="Alumno" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" name="busqueda"
                id="busqueda" placeholder="Buscar">
        </form>

        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Nombre</th>
                    <th><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> Plan de estudio</th>
                    <th><i class="fa fa-university"></i> Curso</th>
                    <th><i class="fa fa-toggle-off"></i> Estado</th>
                    <th><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i> Acciones</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="BusquedaRapida">
                <?php echo $table; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br>
        <div class="paginador">
            <ul>
                <?php echo $paginador; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        (function($) {
            $('#FiltrarContenido').keyup(function() {
                var ValorBusqueda = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'i');
                $('.BusquedaRapida tr').hide();
                $('.BusquedaRapida tr').filter(function() {
                    return ValorBusqueda.test($(this).text());
                }).show();
            })
        }(jQuery));
    });
    </script></body></html>
```

@Triby Así llego al segundo formulario, dándo clic en el lápiz coge la id y me muestra la información para editarla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Primero, si es obligatorio incluir un archivo al crear asignaturas, agrega el atributo `required` para que no se puede procesar el formulario si no se seleccionó un archivo. También conviene agregarlo al nombre de la asignatura.

Aunque haya errores en el formulario, puedes conservar el nombre de asignatura creado y agregarlo en el atributo `value`; en la siguiente parte se ve cómo obtenerlo.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">               
    <label for="Descripcion">Nombre de la asignatura:</label>
    <input type="text" name="nombre_asignatura" required value="<?php echo $nombre_asignatura; ?>">
    <label>Plan curricular anual:</label>
    <input type="file" name="plan_estudio" accept="application/pdf" required>
    <input type="submit" value="&#128190; Guardar" class="btn_save">
</form>
```

En PHP realiza las validaciones necesarias, para que siempre se solicite el archivo, asegurándote de tener valores adecuados y, si no existen, con el [operador de fusión null](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) poner como cadena vacía:

```
<?php
include "dbcon.php";
// Se obtiene aquí para conservar en caso de errores
$nombre_asignatura = $_POST['nombre_asignatura'] ?? '';
$rutaPrograma = "";
// Ejecutar solo si hay una petición por $_POST
if(isset($_POST['nombre_asignatura'])) {
    // Validar que el nombre no está vacío, se subió archivo, no hay error y es del tipo esperado
    if(
        $nombre_asignatura != ''
        && isset($_FILES['plan_estudio'])
        && $_FILES['plan_estudio']['error'] == 0
        && $_FILES["plan_estudio"]["type"] == "application/pdf"
    ) {
        // Antes de otra cosa, deberías validar
        // que no existe una asignatura con este nombre
        $nombre = mt_rand(10, 999);
        $rutaPrograma = "plan_clases/Prog-" . $nombre . ".pdf";
        // ¿Se pudo mover el archivo correctamente a su destino?
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["plan_estudio"]["tmp_name"], $rutaPrograma)) {
            $query_insert = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO asignatura(nombre_asignatura,plan_estudio)VALUES('$nombre_asignatura','$rutaPrograma')");
            if($query_insert) {
                $alert = '<p class="msg_save">Asignatura creada correctamente.</p>';
            } else {
                $alert = '<p class="msg_error">Error al crear la asignatura.</p>';
            }
        } else {
            $alert = '<p class="msg_error">No se pudo mover el archivo.</p>';
        }
    } else {
        $alert = '<p class="msg_error">Debes teclear nombre de asignatura y subir un archivo PDF.</p>';
    }
}
```

Cuando editas una asignatura, solo el nombre es obligatorio, porque se supone que se debió subir un archivo al crearla y, en resumen, debes seguir estos pasos:

1. Obtener ID de asignatura por $_GET o $_POST, depende de cómo tienes el enlace para modificar
2. Validar que existe la asignatura, de lo contrario, mostrar mensaje de error
3. Obtener nombre y archivo actual
4. Si se está procesando el formulario:

   - Validar nombre
   - ¿Se subió archivo?

     - Validar que es correcto
     - Sobrescribir el actual
   - Actualizar datos (consulta UPDATE)
   - ¿Redirigir a otra página? ¿O mostrar la misma con mensaje de éxito?
5. Mostrar formulario, solo el nombre es requerido

Finalmente, te recomiendo migrar a [consultas preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) para minimizar riesgo de errores y ataques SQL.

Comment: el formulario de agregar asignatura si lo tengo bien echo con su **required** y sus **alert**  y si funciona lo adjunte así para mostrar lo mas simple pues quería mostrar los campos y como subía los archivos en pdf; el problema es de que no se como hacer el formulario de editar o sobrescribir el actual como usted dice sin que se me borre la ruta donde se encuentra el pdf